# Yii framework: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: yii, php

What I have:

```
public function beforeValidate() {
    $offender = Accounts::model()->find(array('select'=>'id','condition'=>'username=:username','params'=>array(':username'=>$this->offender)));
    $informer = Accounts::model()->find(array('select'=>'id','condition'=>'username=:username','params'=>array(':username'=>$this->informer)));
    $this->offender = $offender->id;
    $this->informer = $informer->id;
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

What I get:

PHP Notice, that says, that i'm trying to get property "**id**" of **non-object $offender** and **$informer**.

But those are 100% objects:

var_dump($offender):

> object(Accounts)[46]

var_dump($informer):

> object(Accounts)[46]

And it actually sets the right id, but shows that notice anyway. What is wrong?

**SOLVED**
Can't post it as official answer for six more hours, so i just leave it here:

Actually, the problem was in double beforeValidate() call.

AbuseController.php:

```
    if(isset($_POST['AbuseReport']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['AbuseReport'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $model->save();
        }
    }
```

First time it validates on `$model->validate()`, and replaces `$this->offender` and `$this->informer` with correct ID's. Second time it validates on `$model->save();`, but model returns `null` this time, because `$this->offender` is already ID, but it expects username.

**The whole solution** to this is to disable second validation: `$model->save(false);`.

Comment: Can you make a blank page that does nothing other than creating the `$offender` object exactly like in your example, then tries to obtain its `id` property, and see if the error appears there as well?

Comment: You have some limited `var_dump` output, doesnt it show details, like object fields? You sure that notice is in this line?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the notice refers to the lines you just posted? Could it refer to the internals of the framework that receive the `:username` before it being set? (I'm noticing that you're populating `$this->offender` with the *result* of the query, but you're using the property as a *parameter* to the query as well)

Comment: Are you sure that those values exists? You don't validate if the account exists.

Comment: At the end of the post i said, that it actually gets the right model and sets the right id to $this->offender and $this->informer, but shows the notice anyway. And yes, creating `$offender` object in sepatared controller works without any notices. And the var_dump is cut, it is just too long.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure: http://i.imgur.com/hkEbMOT.png . `$this->offender` is being set by form in the first place. I'm trying to replace username (that is being sent from the form) with the id.

Comment: Doesn't `find()` return an *array of results*, in which case you need the `0`th element from it?

Answer (score 0):

use isset or is_object

```
if(isset($offender->id) || is_object($offender->id)){
$this->offender = $offender->id;
$this->informer = $informer->id;
}
```